# Php pass object path to function

Tags: php

this might be super easy. Given is the following object and function:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->a = 'Here we go';
$object->b->first = "again";
$object->b->second = "and again";

function get_item($object, $item){
    print_r($object->{$item});
}

get_item($object, "a"); // works
get_item($object, "b->first"); // NOTICE Undefined property: stdClass::$b
```

While it's working to pass a single property to a function, passing a path like `b->first` fails. Can someone bring me on track how to solve this?

Comment: There's __no__ easy way. PHP cannot understand that `->` in your string is an operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it directly, but you can do it level by level, so in the function use `explode()` to split it into each level and apply it one at a time...

```
function get_item($object, $item){
    $output = $object;
    foreach ( explode("->", $item) as $level )  {
        $output = $output->{$level};
    }
    print_r($output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this way, instead of `get_item($object, "b->first");` use `get_item($object->b, "first");`

```
<?php
$object = new stdClass();

$object->b = new stdClass();
$object->b->first = "again";
$object->b->second = "and again";

function get_item($object, $item){
    print_r($object->{$item});
}


get_item($object->b, "first");
?>
```

Comment: I just wanted to add the almost exact same answer - so have my vote :D

Comment: One could ask a question why have a function at all?